# Empty __init__ list

Tags: python, list, class, init

```
class rand:

    def __init__(self):
        self.c = []

c = rand()

len(c)
```

I am trying to get an empty list in **init**.

So, what I am expecting from the code above is this: len(c) = 0

TypeError: object of type 'rand' has no len()
But I keep getting the error above. How do I get the result above?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the builtin `__len__` method:

```
class rand:
   def __init__(self):
      self.c = []
   def __len__(self):
      return len(self.c)

c = rand()
print(len(c))
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: @J.New That wasn't in your question. You need to be clearer about what you want. It *sounds* like you want `rand` to actually be a subclass of `list`.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @J.New glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `c` and its attribute of the same name are two different objects. You want `len(c.c)`, not `len(c)`.